# Cannot Access Network Manager

Tags: networking, network-manager

I followed the instructions at:
https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2022.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html
The only modifications I made were to add partitions for SLOG, and L2ARCH. I succeeded, and I am now able to boot Ubuntu on it.

I opted to have network access managed graphically, and followed the instructions in Step 7.2. Now the computer does not have network access. I verified NetworkManager is installed just as would be expected by using the command nmcli --version which returns version 1.36.6. Yet I do not see its icon in the task bar in the upper right corner of the screen.

I attempted to follow the instructions at:
https://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/ubuntu-network-manager/
to start up NetworkManager. I got this error:

```
sudo netplan generate
/etc/netplan/01-newtork-manager-all.yaml:3:8: Invalid YAML: mapping values are not allowed in this context:
version: 2
       ^
```

What do I need to do to get the Network Manager working?

The complete YAML file is as given in Step 7.2. For clarity I have pasted it in its entirety from there to here:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

I would like very much copy and paste the file from the Target Computer to here. I cannot because it does not have network access right now. I have, however, just now verified that the above as is seen is the letter, for letter, the entire content of that file.

I do not have a terminal emulator record of the exact response to each command. I do have a text file that contains the commands I used to do the installation, so that in the future, I can do it again if need be. I have uploaded this to a file sharing site. Its download link is: https://www.mediafire.com/file/2w8mdb96tbzslub/Ubuntu_22.04_Root_on_ZFS_Encryption.odt/file

The installation was done mostly by means of SSH connection for the convenience of being able to copy, and paste, the commands from my document. I did not SSH again after Step 7.4. and instead did the remaining steps on the Target Computer directly. Everything was done up to Step 8.5.

Comment: Edit your question to show us the complete YAML of that file. Correct formatting is vital.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages **you** got on **your system**. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: I edited the original question to add the information you asked for. It was too much to put in comments.

Comment: The YAML in Step 7.2 is correct, though that's not what I asked for -- I asked for the actual YAML on your system. The error message suggests that you failed to copy it accurately. Again, correct formatting (including indentation, and correct use of tabs vs. spaces) is critical. Attention to detail is how you fix the problem.

Comment: You were right. I was not aware how sensitive a YAML is to formatting.  I read up on it. It did not work because the double space indents were not there, and the network keyword did not have its colon. All works now. Thanks.